# Capturing a string in a specific format

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, regex, winforms

I have a requirement to capture a string in a specific format of `* [Numeric Digits] *`. This is how I have done right now but I think it would be faster with Regular Expressions. I don't have a lot of experience with RegEx, so please help me optimize this code using RegEx.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(BarcodeScan) && e.KeyChar.ToString() == "*")
    BarcodeScan = e.KeyChar.ToString();
else
{
    if (BarcodeScan.StartsWith("*"))
    {
        if (int.TryParse(e.KeyChar.ToString(), out i))
            BarcodeScan += i.ToString();

        else if (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "*")
        {
            BarcodeScan += "*";
            ArticleID = BarcodeScan.Substring(1, BarcodeScan.Length - 2);
        }
        else            
            BarcodeScan = string.Empty;
     }
}
```

The above code is written in KeyPress event so I have to capture the string as the user is doing the input. Basically the first `*` means that the user has started entering Article ID and I keep on capturing numeric digits till he enters another `*`.

This means that

- `*2323` is valid but incomplete
- `*34h` is invalid
- `*343f33` is invalid
- `*3434hsds3 *` is invalid
- **`*3412 *` is valid and complete**

How do I check for `*2323` in regex?  I tried `^\*\d+` but it allows `*22f` as well.

Comment: This free tool is great for testing your expressions http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner. I'm not associated with the company, just a grateful user :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you possibly provide more samples of your data? In any case, try this

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[*]\d+[*]$");
```

If you actually expect the brackets (e.g. []) using the following:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[*][\[]\d+[]][*]$");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Could you please check out my question again as I have given more details of what I want to do. What would be the regex to check *NumericDigits but disallow anything else

Comment: To check for `*2323` use `^[*][\[]\d+$`

Comment: it didnt work. What is the purpose of [\\[] ? \d+$ means that there should be on or more numerics at the end?

Comment: The `[*]` checks to ensure it starts with a '*'. The `[\[]` checks to ensure the next character is '['. The `\d+` checks to ensure it has a series of digits. I ran a test for `*[123` on http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html and a match was found. Wait... Sorry, I misread your sample data you wanted to test `*123`. My bad... use `^[*]\d+$`

Comment: thanks for your help! Sorry I could not vote up as I do not have reputation of 15.

Comment: No problem, just glad to help